# Can I connect a printer directly to a router and send prints through home Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, printer, network-printer

I was looking for a good multifunction budget printer for home use. HP 1515 seems good, but it does not support Wi-Fi. This will be an issue if I need to send prints from my laptop.

Can I connect this printer directly to the router and send the prints through the home Wi-Fi network, without the need for a separate print server?

What is this functionality is called? Does this printer have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Network printer, either by Ethernet port (cable) or Wi-Fi (wireless).
No - The HP1515 only has USB port.

Workaround: Connect it to a computer that is on the network and always turned on. Then share the printer for other computers to use (they also need to be on the same network, either by cable or wireless).

Comment: Thanks,but running a print server just for printing is not possible,so i will need to get a wifi printer :(

Comment: Unless it's unpractical for you, i would suggest using cable whenever possible. Wi-Fi is subject to signal interference and signal loss. Good luck!

Comment: Running a print server is impossible for me,i also dont want to plug in the usb cable every time i want to take a print from my laptop.

Comment: I meant network cable over wi-fi.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect as you say, if you **buy a router that includes a print server**.

This is much cheaper than buying a router and then a separate print server. On the other hand, if you already have a router, you'd have to get a new one...

D-Link makes some of these: here is an example, the [DI-704UP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CEPDO).

Look for "routers with print server", or with USB connection for printer, there are many around.

Be advised that these integrated print servers are quite "cheap", they can have somewhat limited functionality (like not being able to print a very, very large document or image, due to insufficient memory).

The upside of this way of connecting is that you **don't have to leave a computer always on**, just to share a printer.

Comment: I already have a router,buying a new router is a no go.Running a print server is impossible for me,i also dont want to plug in the usb cable every time i want to take a print from my laptop

Comment: What do you mean when you say "print server"? A dedicated PC just to share a printer? Because it can be that, or a standalone device.

Comment: Its a dedicated pc,if i can turn on the pc,then i can print from it.No need for a laptop,right?

Comment: I was once in the same dilemma as you, and I ended up buying a D-Link like the one I showed you. My rationale was that the new router was pretty cheap; I could make good use of the old router elsewhere; and the extra cost of a network printer was more than what I payed for the new router. Plus there are some practical advantages.

Comment: It costs around $16 more for WIFI functionality.For the local store price of a non wifi printer i can get a wifi printer online for about $80.

Comment: I agree that dedicated PC's just to share a printer are a bad idea, and having to turn them on just to print from another device is not good. But when people say "print server" they normally mean a standalone device (wired or wireless, stuff like http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A13983761%2Ck%3Awireless+print+server&keywords=wireless+print+server&ie=UTF8&qid=1423848117&rnid=493964&ajr=2). Anyway, for you, the right move seems to be simply buying a network printer like you said.

Comment: Im a programmer,so when i say print server i mean a pc connected to a printer :) The print server hardware itself costs $40 which makes it impractical for home use.